# Syncing changes in an SVN repository with a folder on my server

Tags: php, svn

I work for a consumer software company. Our core software runs on the desktop (as opposed to in a browser) and uses a lot of XML and audio files. We're frequently committing new versions of the XML files (and sometimes audio files) to our SVN repository.

However, we have an additional online-only application that uses these same XML and audio files. Assume these files are stored in `http://example.com/data/xml` and `http://example.com/data/audio`. Is there a way to automatically check on a daily basis for new commits to the SVN repository, and then update the `/data/xml` and `/data/audio` folders with the new files found in SVN?

I'm using PHP on Apache.

Comment: Only by apache or the cron can be a valid solution?

Comment: May be you're interested in *fsvs*, a brother of *svn*, thought for sync files with different approach (without ".svn" dirs inside the files):

http://fsvs.tigris.org/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might look [here](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/nightly/en/svn.ref.reposhooks.post-commit.html). That describes **post-commit hooks**. That means you might write a script which is executed on your server after every commit to the repository e.g a script which updates these two directories.

If you just want to update them daily you might look for daily cronjobs(see e.g. here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cron).

Comment: This is exactly what what i was going to suggest, use a post-commit hook and have your files sync'd as soon as you commit them. If once a day is what you really want, then a cronjob is the way to go. The cronjob could eventaully just do an svn checkout of the repo to the location of your http server files ( followed by permission changes required for www users ).

Answer (score 1):

Keep it simple.  Assuming the two folders you want to update are working copies and not locally edited where you want them updated, just run a daily cron that issues a svn update on each folder.